# Serilog sink works in console but fails in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I use Serilog.Sinks.Graylog to log my message to external graylog server. When I log messages in simple console application it will go good. But when I log same way in WCF service - it will fail with strong name validation failed.

How can I solve this problem? This library available through nuget.

Comment: Hi - you'll need to post the exact message and full stack trace from the exception for this one, the answer will depend on which assembly is failing validation and how. Thanks!

Comment: It were Serilog.Sinks.Graylog. I recompiled source without sign key and it worked perfectly well.